# How to merge two arrays negative numbers into one array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to merge negative numbers from two arrays. So what I am doing: adding as much as I want elements to an array, and then trying to add to merged array elements which are <0. This is my try code:

```
int main()
{

    int arr1[100], arr2[100], size1, size2, size, i, j, k, merge[200];
    cout<<"Enter Array 1 Size : ";
    cin>>size1;
    cout<<"Enter Array 1 Elements : ";
    for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr1[i];
    }
    cout<<"Enter Array 2 Size : ";
    cin>>size2;
    cout<<"Enter Array 2 Elements : ";
    for(i=0; i<size2; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr2[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]<0)
        {
          merge[i]=arr1[i];
        }

    }

    size=size1+size2;
    for(i=0, k=size1; k<size && i<size2; i++, k++)
    {
         if(arr2[i]<0)
        {
        merge[k]=arr2[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Now the new array after merging is :\n";
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<merge[i]<<" ";
    }

}
```

after compiling, I am getting wrong merged array. It's printing all negative numbers and also all positive numbers(but in random numbers 2084562 and etc). Maybe you know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a logic mistake in the 2 loops that set the elements of the merged array. They skip the index in the mixed array every time the value is not negative. The skipped values are still uninitialized when printed, so they could theoretically be anything (actually it's undefined behavior).

An example of how to solve this could be creating an integer that counts the number of elements in the merged array set. For example:

```
int negativecount = 0;
for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
{
    if(arr1[i]<0)
    {
      merge[negativecount++]=arr1[i];
    }
}
size=size1+size2;
for(i=0; i<size2 && negativecount < size; i++)
{
    if(arr2[i]<0)
    {
        merge[negativecount++]=arr2[i];
    }
}
```

This way, you'll keep track of the number of elements you've already stored and all elements will be set correctly. You can them print them using:

```
for(i = 0; i < negativecount; ++i)
{
    std::cout << merge[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could tell me how to multiply those negative numbers array elements?

Comment: Do you mean multiplying all negative numbers in the array?

Comment: I mean i need to multiply all that new array values(so yes all negatives, becouse there is only negatives :))

Comment: Try something like this: set a variable to the first value in the merge array outside the loop you use to print the variables. Then on every iteration, use the *= operator with the current element to multiply. Of course, this does require the array to have at least 1 value in it (you can check for that in an if-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is really wrong with the code. But some of the elements in your merged arrays do not get initialized. That is why you get random numbers at the positions of the positive numbers.

Use a separate integer to count how many negative numbers you stored to assign new negative numbers in the merged array or initialize the complete array at 0s first.

For example replace the last part with the code below to merge the arrays nicely in one array.

```
int k = 0; //number of negative elements
for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
{
    if(arr1[i]<0)
    {
      merge[k]=arr1[i];//note we use k as index since i might skip some positions when there are positive elements
      k++;
    }

}

size=size1+size2;

for(i=0; k<size && i<size2; i++)
{
     if(arr2[i]<0)
    {
        merge[k]=arr2[i]; 
        k++; //only increment when we have a negative number
    }
}

cout<<"Now the new array after merging is :\n";
for(i=0; i<k; i++) //note that k is the real size that you used for negative elements.
{
    cout<<merge[i]<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're feeling masochistic, you want to use `std::copy_if` and `std::vector` instead of arrays and hand-written loops.